# Corona SDK: black screen on Composer transition

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

```
    -- hide device status bar
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- require controller module
local composer = require( "composer" )

-- load first scene
local scrOptions =
{
effect = "fromRight",
time = 2000
}

composer.gotoScene( "game", scrOptions )

--
-- Display objects added below will not respond to storyboard transitions

local MemUsageDisplay = display.newText( "0", 400, 25, native.systemFont, 20 )
MemUsageDisplay:setFillColor( gray )
local monitorMem = function()
local textMem = system.getInfo( "textureMemoryUsed" ) / 1000000
collectgarbage()
local date = os.date( "*t" )
MemUsageDisplay.text = date.hour .. ":" .. date.min .. ":" .. date.sec .. " / Lua: " .. math.round(collectgarbage("count")) .. "K " .. "Tex: " .. math.round(textMem*10) * 0.1 .. "MB"
end
timer.performWithDelay( 500, monitorMem, 0 )
```

In the simulator everything is fine.

On the device however the splashscreen flashes for less than a second, then the screen goes black for about 5 seconds, and then the game starts.

There is no transition.

I have to add that my game.lua contains a lot of code, but if I understand the docs correctly, all of that should be processed while the splashscreen is visible? I also ran the app while watching it in debugging mode (catlog...) and put some markers in it to see how fast the code executes. The whole game.lua is processed in less than a second.

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What is the parameter required for composer.gotoScene( "game", scrOptions )?

You need to figure it out in composer library.

have you decrease the time and change the effect in your scrOptions array?

Just try this and let me know what are you getting.

So i can do the further investigation.

Comment: The only required param for gotoScene is the name of the scene, omitting the parameters doesn't change anything on the device, it still goes black for a couple of seconds.

Comment: In you game.lua have you used timer to display your background? Could you provide me the composer library?

Comment: composer is an integrated library of the Corona SDK

Comment: Oh…I apologize. this is the new feature of corona and i am not working  for last 4-5 months….

Comment: Not exactly new, it's the replacement of Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to me that you are not creating  your scene in the scene:create() event function but in the scene:show() event function.  Your transition is set for 2 seconds and if you are not creating anything in scene:create() then there won't be anything to transition, but the transition will still take place, ergo going black for a couple of seconds.

Rob

Comment: scene:create() holds the bulk of my code, including all displayobjects. Also, if I hadn't, it would also show in the simulator, which it doesn't, it just happens on the device. Also, the black screen remains much longer than 2 seconds (in fact it's even there if I remove the transition altogether).

Comment: Could this be related to [this thread](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/43232-short-black-screen-after-defaultpng/) even though most of the entries are about iOS issues? The symptoms sound very much the same, and the long delay could be because it's a slow device.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code
    local scene = composer.newScene()

If everything is working fine in simulator, that means please check in your code whether your using the proper file name (i.e image name and scene names are correct) since simulator will take Image.png and image.png as same, but in device it will show error.